# Ant on a Chess board

Tags: java, arrays

currently my program is only always giving me 4, how can I determine how many steps the ant took to cover the whole board? The ant can walk up down left right, but can't walk off the board, and then do this simulation 4 times.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[][] grid = new int[8][8];

    int count = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0; // arrays are 0 based
    while(true)
    {
        int random =  (int)Math.random()*4+1;
        if (random == 1)
        {
            x--; // move left
        }
        else if (random == 2)
        {
            x++; // move right
        }
        else if (random == 3)
        {
            y--; // move down
        }
        else if (random == 4)
        {
            y++; // move up
        }
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= grid.length || y >= grid[x].length) break;
        count++;
        grid[x][y]++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of Steps in this simulation: " + count); // number of moves before it fell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this expression:

```
int random =  (int)Math.random()*4+1;
```

Through the explicit cast, only `Math.random()` ist casted to `int`. But since `Math.random()` returns a `dobule < 1`, it is casted to `0` and thus `random` is always `1` and the method always returns `0`.

The problem can be fixed by casting `Math.random() * 4`:

```
int random = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
```

The parenthesis enforce that the value of `Math.random() * 4` (which will be a value in the interval `[0, 3)`) will be casted to `int`.

---

Two remarks on your code:

- I would recommend introducing an `enum Direction` with four values (one for each direction) and choose a random `Direction` by calling `Direction.values()[(int) (Math.random() * 4)];`
- I would recommend to use a `switch` instead of the `if-else-if` cascade.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/oeDqXB)

Comment: I am not very confident in doing an enum direction any tips how to go about it?

Comment: Great code! but for some reason I am getting exception

Answer (score 0):

The program will exit the `while(true)` loop once one of the 4 conditions is true. My suggestion is to move these conditions in your `if(random == value)` checks like this:

```
if( random == 1 )
 {
   x--;
   if (x < 0 )
    {
      x++;
    }
 }
```

Now to exit your `while(true)` loop you need to have an extra condition. I would suggest to think about your board in terms of 0's and 1's. Everytime the ant cross a cell, you set the `grid[x][y] = 1`.

```
int stepsTaken = 0;
int cellsToCover = grid.length * grid[0].length ;
int coveredCells = 0;
while(true)
{
 //your code here
 if( random == 1 )
  {
    stepsTaken++;
    x--;
    if (x < 0 )
    {
      x++;
    }
  }
  // the other if's with "stepsTaken" incremented too.
  if ( grid[x][y] == 0 )
  {
    grid[x][y] = 1;
    coveredCells++;
  }
  if (coveredCells == cellsToCover )
    break;
 }
```

But please notice the many `if`s statements inside a `while(true)` loop. If you have to fill a board of 10 rows x 10 columns it would take too much until the board is filled. Instead I would suggest you to use some more efficient algorithms like backtracking, dynamic programming etc.

**Edit** : Added step counter.

Comment: "*The program will exit the while(true) loop once one of the 4 conditions is true.*" - That is not correct. Condition #2 and #4 will lead to further iterations.

Comment: I was talking about this if : `if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= grid.length || y >= grid[x].length) break;`

Comment: The grid size is irrelevant for the count of `if`-statements. The code works perfectly fine. The intention is not a round trip (i.e. visiting each field once), but to simulate a random walk until the ant leaves the board.

Comment: "cover the whole board" and "but can't walk off the board" got me thinking that the ant keep walking until it covers the board, and when it is about to walk off the board, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: well if this is what OP wants, then the code does not reflect that in any way.

Comment: The results should show how many steps the ant took to cover the whole board, if it was about to fall off, then it doesn't count as a step but doesn't fall,  and it goes back to trying to cover the whole board.

Comment: Then I suggest to take my advice and remove the conditions from the last if, and try to use some more efficient algorithms over the plain `if` statements, or, at least use @Turing85 suggest of using `switch` statements.

Comment: @CyT3 if the program should run until each field was visited at least once, then your code is far from being a solution.

Comment: That is the tricky part for me, as I am not quite sure how to create the code for this problem :/